# Return collection with flag for if items have children

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to return a collection of customers, which works but I would like to make my call efficient so that each of the records brought back should have a Boolean return to see if that customer has children (addresses).

whats the most efficient call that will return me all the customers including a flag for each to determine if children are present

below is my current code for just retrieving customers (relationship between customer and address is through customerID on address table)

using entity framework 6.1

```
  public static List<Customer> GetCustomers()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var context = new MyContext())
            {
                return (from c in context.Customers
                        select c).ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new CustomerException(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would not return a List<Customer>, while customer would have a property for Addresses, you would need another property most likely a bool indicating whether there are Addresses or not. so you would need to create something like a dto (data transfer object) class. seeing that I would rather call count on the Addresses to fill the value, perhaps you may instead of a bool field, rather use an integer ands set the integer value to Customer.Addresses.Count()

Answer (score 0):

I would perhaps do something like this.

```
public class CustomerDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int AddressCount { get; set; }
}

var result = from w in context.Customers select new { Name = w.Name, AddressCount = w.Addresses.Count };

        var ret = new List<CustomerDto>();

        foreach (var customer in result)
        {
            var newCustomerDto = new CustomerDto();
            newCustomerDto.Name = customer.Name;
            newCustomerDto.AddressCount = customer.AddressCount;
        }

return ret;
```

This is a simple example, and should serve as a starting point for you.
I don't have VS open, so just check the code, but it looks good to me. I forgot to mention that if it is only a flag that you are after, instead of .Count you can use .Any

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
public static List<Customer> GetCustomers()
{
    try
    {
        using (var context = new MyContext())
        {
            return (from c in context.Customers
                    where c.Address.Any()
                    select c).ToList();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new CustomerException(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex);
    }
}
```